# InstallShield 2012: have installscript msi project execute a MSI file that it just installed

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have a client that already generates a MSI file for each of their web appliations.  They want an InstallShield wrapper installation that will allow a user to select which web application(s) they want and have InstallShield put the appreciate MSI file(s) on the user's machine and then execute each MSI file.  I have seen posts about running 3rd party MSI files that are prereq's but not this situation.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible the way you request it.  There's a Mutex that prevents an MSI to install another MSI.  For InstallShield 2012, you should look at "Suite" projects.

Comment: Convinced client that they did not need to build an .msi and could configure folders and files that would be installed directly in IS via Components

Comment: @Christopher Painter Sorry for Hijacking this, but is there any way to do it without suite? I only have professional, but need to run my installation, then run another .msi (that installs something my program relies on)

Comment: Take a look at the doco on setup prerequisites and feature prerequisites.  You'll have to build each of your feature as an MSI and then create PRQ files for each of them.  Then create a parent MSI that's driven by setup.exe that consumes those MSI's as Feature Prereqs.  The feature selection in the MSI will cause setup.exe to run the correct MSI's.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. The solution I chose was to put a rectangle on the next string of code to disable any input in date string.

```
<Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a custom action and launched the MSI.. So the install wait for the other msi to complete then once done it will run the usual intall.

Also ensure that you have scheduled the custom action in the UI sequence. Two MSI’s cannot run simultaneously in execute sequence.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Custom actions scheduled in the UI sequence 1) won't get run during silent installs and 2) won't always run elevated.  This is not a proper solution.

Comment: The user didnt mention it should be ran as silent install.. If so would have checked for other solution. so if not silent install, this will be a solution.

Comment: There are a whole host of best practices that a user will never know to ask for but that's not an excuse for designing a poor solution.